# Error filtering template: File Magento 2.1.6

Tags: magento2, upgrade

I have upgraded website from 2.1.5 to 2.1.6.
I am facing Error filtering template: File pub/media/catalog/product/placeholder/default/image.jpg' does not exists.

Place holder image is already there at above path.

I have also tried to upload new place holder image from the admin catalog configuration but still error exists.